# AngularJs - Create public pages and restric pages

Tags: angularjs

I need to create some pages with restrictions and my code works fine but when I try to access pages that have an ID none works and automatically redirects me to the login. Can anyone tell me why?

```
function run($rootScope, $http, $location,  $localStorage) {
    // keep user logged in after page refresh
    if ($localStorage.currentUser) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.currentUser;
    }


    // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current, Auth) {
        var publicPages = ['/login','/','/job','/job/:jobId'];
        var restrictedPage = publicPages.indexOf($location.path()) === -1;
        if (restrictedPage && !$localStorage.currentUser) {
            $location.path('/login');
        } 
    });
}
```

My config

```
    .when("/job" , {
        templateUrl: "app/components/job/views/job.html",
        controller: "job"
    })
    .when("/job/:jobId" , {
        templateUrl: "app/components/job/views/jobdetail.html",
        controller: "job_detail"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your verification for public pages is wrong.

The path `/job/:jobId` is only a route.
Calling `$location.path()` returns the current path where the parameter is substituted and so returns `/job/1` which is not in your `publicPages` array.

I would also recommend using [ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It makes your life a lot easier and there are a lot tutorials how to use it (e.g. [Handling basic route authorization in AngularJS](https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2015/08/handling-basic-route-authorization-in-angularjs/))

Comment: when i put the location.path i have the value but i can't put in my array.

Comment: I know. That is the reason I suggested that you rethink your current approach. Take a look at the link I inserted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ui.router then you can implement a scalable solution as follows. In this example any state start with app requires authentication. Login to the app using test@gmail.com as the email as password as 123. ui.router hooks does the trick!.

```
  .run(($transitions, $state, $injector) => {
    $transitions.onBefore({
      to: 'app.**'
    }, () => {
      const $window = $injector.get('$window');
      if (!$window.sessionStorage.getItem('user')) {
        return $state.target('login', $state.transition.params());
      }
      return true
    });
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCN2hB34mMEmBJulyaAJ?p=preview